# magento get null value in $(pair.value) product_option.js

Tags: magento-1.9, prototype-js

I have a problem in product_option.js
I have configurable product when I change the product option it will not show with changing amount, I already add product_option.js,
when I track the prototype I find in product_option.js
line number 128,

```
if ($(pair.value)) { ............. }
```

I get null value in $(pair.value)

I want, instead of null I get the value of total price with additionally amount.

Comment: If you are getting a `null` value it probably is because you have removed the clone price on the configurable page. I would say restore to default and apply your changes carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debug the my error,
sometimes theme show the error like:

```
Product.OptionsPrice is not a constructor
```

so we add the in layout file:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
```

But after adding above line error gone from console but still when we change any option price not change.

After debugging I see theme use own **price.phtml** and it pass null value so I just comment it and magento directly call base **price.phtml** file and then its working.